# Datagrid does not show data

Tags: json, jsp, spring-mvc, datagrid

Here is my datagrid part in jsp:

```
<title>Device</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dataGrid;
$(function() {
    dataGrid = $('#dataGrid').datagrid({
        url : '${ctx}' + '/drivers/dataGrids',
        striped : true,
        rownumbers : true,
        pagination : true,
        singleSelect : true,
        idField : 'id',
        sortName : 'driversstatus',
        sortOrder : 'desc',
        pageSize : 15,
        pageList : [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 ],
        frozenColumns : [ [ {
            width : '100',
            title : 'id',
            field : 'id',
            sortable : true
        }, {
            width : '80',
            title : 'Device Name',
            field : 'driversname',
            sortable : true
        } , {
            width : '80',
            title : 'Device ip',
            field : 'driversip',
            sortable : true
        }, {
            width : '80',
            title : 'Device type',
            field : 'driverstype',
            sortable : true,
        }, {
            width : '80',
            title : 'Device Status',
            field : 'driversstatus',
            sortable : true,
            formatter : function(value, row, index) {
                switch (value) {
                case 0:
                    return 'Online';
                case 1:
                    return 'Offline';   
                }
            }
        } ,{
            width : '80',
            title : 'Add Time',
            field : 'addtime',
            sortable : true,
        }
         ] ],
        toolbar : '#toolbar'
    });
});
```

And here is my datagrid code in controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/dataGrids")
@ResponseBody
public Grid jsonList(Drivers eqimInfo, PageFilter ph) {
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.setPage(ph.getPage());
    grid.setRows(driversService.dataGrid(eqimInfo, ph));
    grid.setTotal(driversService.Count(eqimInfo, ph));
    return grid;
}
```

Grid.class contains private attributes including page, rows and rowsCount, and their getter and setter; Drivers.class is the data class.

I can confirm that the returned Grid instances contains every data retrieved from the database, but the strange thing is that every columns have their values shown except the "Device Name" column, which drives me crazy......

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Turns out that the first letter of the field in mySQL should use lower cases, otherwise jsp would not recognize it.